# How to use Packer Salt provisioner to create docker images?

Tags: salt-stack, packer

How to use Packer Salt provisioner to create docker images ?

here is my `packer.json` file. I will comment inline below

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "docker",
      "image": "enonic/docker-salt-masterless-ubuntu",
      "export_path": "cassandra.tar" // Not sure what this is doing?
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "/srv/salt/cassandra", // This is where the cassandra directory is on my host machine which is ubuntu
      "destination": "/srv/salt/cassandra" // This is where I expect the cassandra directory on my host machine gets copied to inside a docker container
    },
    {
      "type": "salt-masterless",
      "local_state_tree": "/srv/salt/cassandra",
      "custom_state": "/srv/salt/cassandra/init.sls",
      "disable_sudo": true
    }
  ]
}
```

`sudo docker build packer.json`

**I get the following error**

```
Build 'docker' errored: Failed to upload to '/srv/salt/cassandra' in container: Error response from daemon: lstat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/0c6a422400a073624a66b00580a6b9e5551e82a06495c46b1f840b38ca55699d/srv/salt: no such file or directory
. exit status 1.

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> docker: Failed to upload to '/srv/salt/cassandra' in container: Error response from daemon: lstat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/0c6a422400a073624a66b00580a6b9e5551e82a06495c46b1f840b38ca55699d/srv/salt: no such file or directory
```

It would be great if I can get a simple working example on how to use salt state files from host machine and build a docker image using packer. My cassandra state files are same as https://github.com/salt-formulas/salt-formula-cassandra

My `top.sls` file looks like this

```
base:
  'client*-es-*':
    - roles-elasticsearch
  'client*-cassandra-*':
    - roles-cassandra


  'P@os:(Debian|Ubuntu) and P@roles:(elasticsearch|cassandra)':
    - match: compound
    - deb-common

  'roles:elasticsearch':
    - match: grain
    - disk-raid0-3volumes
    - disk-elasticsearch
    - elasticsearch
    - elasticsearch.cerebro
  'roles:cassandra':
    - match: grain
    - disk-raid0-3volumes
    - disk-cassandra
    - cassandra
```

I just want to build a docker container image only for cassandra but not for everything in my `top.sls`. so how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I adjusted your example to be simpler and just install Apache 2.

The `shell` provisioner is just because I don't know salt and din't spend any time on howto do `apt-get update`.

First of all the base image already have salt installed so use `skip_bootstrap`. You *shouldn't upload the state directory* to the guest (Docker container) since this is done automatically, all this is in the documentation [Packer - Salt Masterless](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/salt-masterless.html). `local_state_tree` should point at the base of your salt state tree i.g. `/srv/salt` in you case.

A working example:

**Tree**

```
.
├── salt
│   ├── apache
│   │   └── init.sls
│   └── top.sls
└── template.json
```

**Template.json**

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "docker",
      "image": "enonic/docker-salt-masterless-ubuntu",
      "export_path": "apache2.tar"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": [
        "apt-get update"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "salt-masterless",
      "local_state_tree": "salt",
      "skip_bootstrap": true,
      "disable_sudo": true
    }
  ]
}
```

**top.sls**

```
base:
  '*':
    - apache
```

**apache/init.sls**

```
apache2:
  pkg.installed: []
  service.running:
    - require:
      - pkg: apache2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Is your top.sls and apache/init.sls are in host or in guest (docker). In my case all salt files are in host. so how would salt-call inside docker container know about my state files that are located in the host machine? so how is it done automatically?

Comment: I get the following error  `* local_state_tree: path 'salt' is invalid: stat salt: no such file or directory`

Comment: They are in the host. And it works because `salt-masterless` starts by uploading them to a temp directory on the guest before executing `salt`.

Comment: Thank you so much again. One last question. I had pasted my top.sls in my question so can you please explain how to install only Cassandra but not everything in my top.sls ? Will be super glad to accept your answer. please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `local_state_path`  to `/srv/salt`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks you so much. I think I went pretty far with your example..I am also new to salt and I am trying to use something that is already there so I pasted my top.sls file in my quest and there is a huge list of software but I only want to install cassandra in my docker container nothing else so how will I do that? This is my last question